# Changing image src back to the original image using removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I made a custom pager for my *bxSlider*. I want to change the original grey `img` to the colored image when it is clicked and get class "green". While the clicked pager has class "green" and colored image, I want the other pager stay as the original gray image.

I got to the part where I can replace the original gray `img` to green, and remove the class "green" of the siblings, however, even though the class "green" is removed from the siblings, it still remains as colored `img` instead of going back to the original grey as if `removeClass("green")` is not working.

HTML:

```
<ul id="slidePager">
    <li class="col-md-2 b-conts1">
        <a href="#" data-slide-index="0">
            <img src="img/benefit-lowcost-g.png" class="b-cost" alt="low cost icon" >
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-2 b-conts2">
        <a href="#" data-slide-index="1">
            <img src="img/benefit-logistic-g.png" class="b-logistic" alt="logistics icon" >
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(e){
    $('.b-conts1').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 

        $(this).addClass('green').siblings().removeClass('green');

        if($(this).hasClass('green')){
            $('.b-cost').attr('src','/img/benefit-lowcost-c.png');
        } else {
            $('.b-cost').attr('src','/img/benefit-lowcost-g.png');    
        };
     });

     $('.b-conts2').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).addClass('green').siblings().removeClass('green');

        if($(this).hasClass('green')){
            $('.b-logistic').attr('src','/img/benefit-logistic-c.png');
        } else {
            $('.b-logistic').attr('src','/img/benefit-logistic-g.png');    
        };
     });
});
```

Comment: `if($(this).hasClass('green'))` doesn't refer to the element's sibling - so the condition will always evaluate to `true` since at that stage `$(this)` already has the class `.green` and the `.attr()` method in the `else` block will never run on the sibling element (if it would run, it would run on `$(this)`, the element in scope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As UncaughtTypeError indicated, once you stick the green class on, it's pointless to check if it's there. Instead, toggle the images you want -- if you're changing the image in both the cost and logistic image, then you'll simply set them both in each case.

```js
$(function(e) {
  $('.b-conts1').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).addClass('green').siblings().removeClass('green');

    // Remove the if bit here -- instead, simply set the images
    //  for BOTH cost and logistic. Same below.
    $('.b-cost').attr('src', '/img/benefit-lowcost-c.png');
    $('.b-logistic').attr('src', '/img/benefit-logistic-g.png');
  });

  $('.b-conts2').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).addClass('green').siblings().removeClass('green');
    $('.b-cost').attr('src', '/img/benefit-lowcost-c.png');
    $('.b-logistic').attr('src', '/img/benefit-logistic-g.png');
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
}
li {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.green {
  background-color: #9c9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="slidePager">
  <li class="col-md-2 b-conts1">
    <a href="#" data-slide-index="0">
      <img src="img/benefit-lowcost-g.png" class="b-cost" alt="low cost icon">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="col-md-2 b-conts2">
    <a href="#" data-slide-index="1">
      <img src="img/benefit-logistic-g.png" class="b-logistic" alt="logistics icon">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code in this way:
In this way you simply modify image src(s) so there is no need to populate your js file with all image's src(s) and also on click `add/remove` `.green` class from element and set desire src to the image element and also check `siblings()` too. For removing `.green` from clicked element will do same but reversely.

**jQuery**:

```
$(function(e){
    $("li[class*='b-conts']").on('click', function(e){//[class^="b-conts"]
      e.preventDefault();
      if($(this).hasClass('green')){
         $(this).removeClass('green');
         var source = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
             source = source.slice(0,-5) + 'g.png';
             $(this).find('img').attr('src', source);
      } else {
         $(this).addClass('green');
         $(this).siblings().each(function(){
         if($(this).hasClass('green')){
            $(this).removeClass('green');
           var source = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
               source = source.slice(0,-5) + 'g.png';
               $(this).find('img').attr('src', source);
         }
         });
         var source = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
             source = source.slice(0,-5) + 'c.png';
             $(this).find('img').attr('src', source);
      }
    });
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cb14axbd/)